# How to protect anonymous class creation with Interface reference

Tags: java, interface, anonymous-class

Consider the Business Scenario:

We have `student` Interface with `payFees()` method. There are some classes which implements student interface and implement `payFees` method. These are : `SchoolStudent`, `CollegeStudent`, `UniversityStudent`, `OnlineStudent`.

Now a developer will create the list of student as `List<Student>` and add different students to the list (`SchoolStudent`, `CollegeStudent` etc.).
Now developer can create anonymous class using `Student` interface, implements some faulty `payFees` method and add that object to the studentlist.
This anonymous student is not valid and it will distrub the business logic.

So how we will protect developer from creating anonymous class of `Student` interface.

Comment: The least complex (and probably a bad design) way is to use a proxy / wrapper to add to the arraylist and check for class of the instance before adding. throw an exception if you get a class which is not valid

Answer (score 3):

One way I can think of is (assuming all the valid implementations of `Student` interface are in the same package) to define a package private additional interface (let's call it `ValidStudent`) that the valid implementations implement in addition to implementing `Student`. That package private interface doesn't have to contain any methods.

Then, you can have some code that validates the `Student` instances added to the `List` - that validation code will check that those instances also implement the `ValidStudent` interface. Any custom implementations of `Student` won't pass that validation.

```
package x;
public interface Student
{
    ...
}

package x;
interface ValidStudent // package private
{
    // nothing here
}

package x;
public class SchoolStudent implements Student, ValidStudent
{

}
```

And an example for the validation (the validation can be done by any class in package `x` that does something with `Student` instances) :

```
package x;
public class StudentValidator
{
    public static boolean isValid (Student student) 
    {
        return student instanceof ValidStudent;
    }
}
```

Comment: Or we could do away with the `ValidStudent` interface completely and do a quick dirty check of *clasName contains "$"` when adding to the List (I know its not a good idea :P)

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar This would only cover anonymous implementations of `Student`. What about regular custom  implementations of `Student`?

Comment: Ya. That's true.. The OP will have to take your way.. +1ed long ago :P

Comment: Regular custom implementation of 'Student' still work. This will add extra wrapper to check the student while adding it into the list.

Comment: @Sandeep.K What do you mean by that? Should a regular custom implementation of Student work? What's the difference between a regular custom class and an anonymous custom class? Both can implement Student interface with `some faulty payFees method`.

Comment: You'd also have to make your `payFees()` final in all classes - or the attacker would just create anonymous class based on one of the implementations instead of the interface and you're back to beginning. Doing so (making final) would severly limit your later options for own subclasses - so I don't like that too much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use not `Student` interface but a class `Student` with a package access constructor.

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar and why? ;)

Comment: You shouldn't change interfaces to classes. They are 2 different things

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar I know man, but we can use an abstract class. What do you think? It is the simplest solution :)

Comment: What about, if we create a abstract class with parametrised constructor, which implements 'Student' interface, All child classes will be extends by abstract class. In this way, anonymous will be protected but need a complete design change..? Is there is any other solutions where minimum design changes required??

Comment: @Sandeep.K In this situation you don't need Student interface, because of you can't pass it as a method argument for an example (if do so, you can pass an anonymous implementation too).

Comment: @Sandeep.K I use a simple rule If I don't need it in this moment I don't use it. So you can begin from the simplest design with abstract class and change it to Eran's solution, for an example, only when you really need Student to be an interface.

Comment: @Sandeep.K And the simplest solution with "minimum design changes required" consider your question either theoretical than practical and don't do such design at all. I think, it is pretty useless.

Comment: @v.ladynev Actually I gave a small example. Actually I have a jar where Interface and classes hierarchy is already implemented and I need to work with the object list. This list is used with some other class where list object get processed. In this anonymous object will result the wrong calculation result. Thanks for your answer. I think I need to add Validator for that :-)